# Braising brisket internal temperature

Tags: food-science, beef, braising

I am going to braise 22 pounds of brisket for 6-8 hours at 225°.
What temperature should the brisket be internally before I pull out to cool? I have been told many mixed answers.

Answer (score 6):

After 6-8 hours at 225° your meat's going to be 225°, there's no value of measuring its temperature. After a couple of hours any piece of meat will reach the same temperature of the oven. When cooking tough cuts like brisket target temperature is immaterial, you're never going to serve them less than well done, the point is to cook them long enough for the connective tissue to break down into gelatin.

Measuring temperature is important when roasting tender cuts and you want a particular doneness level.

Comment: So your saying a thermometer is useless when braising tough cuts of meats? Let me rephrase the question the.  If I was to braise 22 pounds of brisket for 7 hours, what temperature should I have the oven at?

Comment: 22 pounds? You're feeding an army @JosephO'Neal! A thermometer isn't completely useless, it can tell you when your meat is up to cooking temperature, which is when the magic happens with tough cuts. I don't bother, if I'm making a lot I just work in extra time for it all to heat up. 225F is a good temperature no matter whether you're cooking 2 or 22 pounds.

Comment: The meat will not be 225—not unless it has been entirely dried out (which won't have happened). It can't really get above boiling until (almost) all the water is gone, except in a pressure cooker.